# Proof verification: Symmetric groups are group. What is a permutation group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

This is not exactly a question but I want someone to confirm if my understanding of the following is correct.

The symmetric group of a set $X$ is the set of all the bijections from $X \to X$. $$S_{X}= \{\sigma: X \to X \mid \sigma \text{ is a bijection} \}$$

**Question 1:** I want to show the above set is a group with respect to the binary operation of composition $\circ : S_X \times S_X \to S_X$. Here is my proof.

1. Since $\sigma_1, \sigma_2 \in S_X$ are bijections, their composition is also a bijection and hence belongs to $S_X$.
2. Composition is associative for any triplet of functions (not necessarily bijections) so associativity holds.
3. $\sigma_e : X \to X$ given by $\sigma_e (x) = x$ is the identity element in $S_X$.
4. Any $\sigma \in S_X$ is bijective, hence invertible and so $\exists \ \sigma^{-1} \in S_X$ such that $\sigma \circ \sigma^{-1}= \sigma_e$

Something about point 3 and 4 doesn't feel right. What is a better way to phrase it?

Is the reasoning in my proof above correct at every step?

**Question 2:** I'm confused about Symmetric group vs Permutation Group. But as I understand it, a symmetric group is the set of **all** the bijections and permutation group is just a subgroup of symmetric group including the Symmetric group. Intuitively, a permutation group is just a collection of bijections on $X$ that form a group with $\circ$. So, one could say: There is only **one** symmetric group on a set while there could be multiple permutation groups on the same set. Is my understanding correct?

For example: $P = \{\pi : ℝ \to ℝ \mid \pi(x) = x+a, \ \forall a \in ℝ \} $ is set of all translations (as well as bijections) is the Permutation group on $\mathbb{R}$ but $P≠S_{ ℝ}$. $P$ is just the group $(ℝ, +)$.

Comment: Q1: Yes. Q2: For $X=\{1,2,\ldots ,n\}$ we have ${\rm Sym}(X)=S_n$, the symmetric group of permutations. Q3: Regarding the name *symmetric group* see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46317/what-kind-of-symmetry-is-the-symmetric-group-about).

Comment: @DietrichBurde I'm sorry, I do not understand your reply to my question 2. Could you elaborate. Sure for $X=\{1,2, \ldots, n \}, S_X = S_n$ is the symmetric group of permutations what does that have to with question 2?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I've also slightly edited question 1 asking for a better way to phrase the points 3 and 4, if you could take a look at that as well.

Comment: For question $2$, I understand the symmetric group $S_n$. It consists of all permutations that can be performed on the $n$  symbols. So what is the difference to your "permutation group"? What do you mean by this?

Comment: Perhaps [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group) is helpful. For finite sets, "permutations" and "bijective functions" refer to the same operation, namely rearrangement.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Are you asking me what a [permutation group](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_group) is? I've also updated my question 2 with an example, does that help? Or are you asking something entirely else?

Comment: Yes, indeed, this was my question. In your link you have also your answer. A permutation group then is a **subgroup** of the symmetric group. Every finite group is a subgroup of some $S_n$.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: @Shaun Okay. I've deleted question 3. Question 1 isn't a question. It's just prove verification. 1 and 2 are both "Yes" or "No" questions.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I see the confusion. I'm not asking a query in question 2. I'm actually saying if whatever I've written in question 2 is correct? I'm asking for confirmation. If my understanding is correct or not. Sorry for the confusion. I don't think naming it "question" 1 or 2 was correct since I'm not actually querying. I'm looking for a confirmation like "yes" or "no" or some thoughts on improving it.

Comment: I am not really sure what the problem is here. The answer to Question 2 is yes, your understanding is correct.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks. English isn't my first language so I was trying to make sure if I'm not misunderstanding anything. Is my example in question 2 correct? The reason I ask this is because though $(P, \circ) = (ℝ, +)$, the more I think, I'm not sure if $(P, \circ)= S_{ℝ}$ or not. At first I thought they weren't. But now I'm not sure. Do they have the same cardinalities or something? Idk.

Comment: A side comment on your Question 1. Hystorically, things went the other way around: the definition of *abstract group* is precisely patterned upon the *properties* 1 to 4 fulfillled by the set of all the bijections on a given set $X$. So the answer is (tautogically) yes, as your $S_X$ is the "prototypical" abstract group.

Comment: @DerekHolt Nevermind I figured it out. $|S_{ℝ}|>|ℝ|=|P|$ so there cannot be a bijection